# (others too)picasso is not working with simple image display using URL

Tags: android, imageurl

```
dependency=implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0"
 
String url1="https://www.google.com/search?

    ImageView image;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        image= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .resize(200,200)         //optional
                .centerCrop()            //optional
                .into(image);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. The literal for `String url1` looks broken. [How does `not working` manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 0):

First please add this URL, and confirm that the image is not uploading:

```
https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg
```

```
Picasso.with( context )
        .load( your_path )
        .error( R.drawable.ic_error )
        .placeholder( R.drawable.progress_animation )
        .into( image_view );
```

Comment: Picasso.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .resize(200,200)         //optional
            .centerCrop()                        //optional
            .into(image);

Comment: Please edit your answer to include additional code, instead of placing it in the comments. Also, did you mean “not uploading”, as you wrote, or “now uploading”?